# C# - Changing Value of Datagridview Multiple Cells Causing Recurive Loop

Tags: c#, recursion, datagridview, stack-overflow

I want to Update the value of datagridview cell(s) of a row if any one cell value of same row is change.

Here is my Code...

```
    private void DGV_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int Qty = Convert.ToInt32(DGV["Qty", rowspan].Value);
            decimal Rate = Convert.ToDecimal(DGV["Rate", rowspan].Value);
            decimal amount = Convert.ToDecimal(DGV["Amount", rowspan].Value);
            decimal Dis1 = Convert.ToDecimal(DGV["Dis1", rowspan].Value);
            decimal Dis1_ = Convert.ToDecimal(DGV[9, rowspan].Value);
            decimal Dis2 = Convert.ToDecimal(DGV["Dis2", rowspan].Value);
            decimal Dis2_ = Convert.ToDecimal(DGV[11, rowspan].Value);
            decimal GST = Convert.ToDecimal(DGV["GST", rowspan].Value);
            decimal GST_ = Convert.ToDecimal(DGV[13, rowspan].Value);
            decimal NetAmt = Convert.ToDecimal(DGV["NetAmt", rowspan].Value);

            DGV["Qty", rowspan].Value = Qty;
            DGV["Rate", rowspan].Value = Rate;
            DGV["Amount", rowspan].Value = Qty * Rate;
            DGV["Dis1", rowspan].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(((Dis1_ * NetAmt) / 100).ToString("N1"));
            DGV[9, rowspan].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(((Dis1 / NetAmt) * 100).ToString("N1"));
            DGV["Dis2", rowspan].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(((Dis2_ * NetAmt) / 100).ToString("N1"));
            DGV[11, rowspan].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(((Dis2 / NetAmt) * 100).ToString("N1"));
            DGV["GST", rowspan].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(((GST_ * NetAmt) / 100).ToString("N1"));
            DGV[13, rowspan].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(((GST_ / NetAmt) * 100).ToString("N1"));
            DGV["NetAmt", rowspan].Value = CalculateNetAmount(amount, Dis1, Dis2, GST);
            lblAmount.Text = totalamount().ToString();
        }
        catch (StackOverflowException ex)
        {
            loglbl.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

currently i'm getting following StackOverflowExcpetion...

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

any Suggestion? How To?

Comment: why are assigning value in same function ...that is issue..but you put button in gird "Update" and that will do update all values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Suggestion for this is , you make use of extra button in your grid "Update" button and when this button get click update value in the grid.

Because right now you are doing changes in value in "DGV_CellValueChanged" function , call that function again , i.e. it is creating recursive loop and you are getting stackoveflow excpetion

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved... I just change event from CellValueChange to CellEndEdit

```
private void DGV_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  //Rest of the code
}
```